# How to move nav link into a drop down

Tags: html, laravel

I  have a drop-down menu that, when I click on the drop-down,  shows the 'logout' link. I  want to add another link to it called "profile" so that when I click the drop-down it provides me both logout and profile.

I am  struggling to do this. I  have "profile" on the side on the navbar, but cannot get the profile tab to go into the drop-down menu:

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
           <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                {{ __('Logout') }}
            </a>
            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                @csrf
            </form>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " href="{{ route('product.shoppingCart')}}">Cart
    <span class = "badge badge-primary">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : ''}}
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " href="{{ route('posts.profile')}}">Profile
    </a>

</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should put the profile link inside the `div` with `dropdown-menu` class and give it a `dropdown-item` class, instead of giving it a `nav-item` class and putting it alongside of the other navbar items. visit https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

I should say that the navbar code is quite untidy. I tried to clean up a little bit and fixed your problem. You have opened a `<div>` tag for your dropdown menu and have not closed it with `</div>`.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('posts.profile')}}">Profile
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                {{ __('Logout') }}
        </a>
    </div>
    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        @csrf
    </form>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " href="{{ route('product.shoppingCart')}}">Cart
        <span class = "badge badge-primary">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : ''}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I put the (invisible) form outside of the dropdown. I believe you do not want it to be inside.

Answer (score 0):

Just this profile on your drop downlist

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">

<a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{{ route('posts.profile')}}" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>Profile
                </a>
                    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                       <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                           onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                            {{ __('Logout') }}
                        </a>
                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                            @csrf
                        </form>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="{{ route('product.shoppingCart')}}">Cart
                <span class = "badge badge-primary">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : ''}}
                </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">


            </li>
```